# Angular: How do I deal with nested FormGroups in the HMLT Template?

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I'm very new to Angular and trying to build a form to collect user information.

Let's say I have a user that can have a "friend" associated with them.  A simplified version of my FormGroup looks like this:

```
userInformation = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   age: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   friend: new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      age: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
   })
})
```

In my HTML, I have:

```
<form [formGroup]="userInformation" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit">
    <input type="text" placeholder="full name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="full name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="full name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="full name">
</form>
```

How do I bind the first two inputs to the userInformation and the second two inputs to the userInformation.friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested formgroups we use `formgroupName`, so all you need to create is a container, where you set the `formGroupName` and the "friend" form controls inside it:

```html
<form [formGroup]="userInformation">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="age" placeholder="age" />
  <ng-container formGroupName="friend">
  <!-- ^^^^^^^^^HERE^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-->
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name" />
    <input type="text" formControlName="age" placeholder="age" />
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! :) :)